# Small Clue game

Tags: java, performance, game

I'm learning Java and was making a program to go along with the board game *Clue*. I type the name of who didn't do it and it takes them off the list. I want to evolve this program to be able to do other things and include the weapons and locations and maybe even probabilities based on other peoples guesses' during the game, but for now I just want this code ripped apart. I know it's ugly. I'm just trying to think of a better way I can write it or different methods to use.

```
package clue;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int[] who = new int[6];
    //int[] what = new int[6];
    //int[] where = new int[9];
    String[] whoRemains = new String[]{"green", "mustard", "peacock", "plum", "scarlet", "white"};
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int counter = 6;
    do {
        System.out.println("Remaing People: ");

        for(int i = 0;i<6;i++){
            if (who[i] == 0){
                System.out.println(whoRemains[i]);  
                }
            }

        String guess = sc.next();
        if (guess.equals("green")){
            who[0]= 1;
            counter--;
            }
        if (guess.equals("mustard")){
            who[1]= 1;
            counter--;
            }
        if (guess.equals("peacock")){
            who[2]= 1;
            counter--;
            }
        if (guess.equals("plum")){
            who[3]= 1;
            counter--;
            }
        if (guess.equals("scarlet")){
            who[4]= 1;
            counter--;
            }
        if (guess.equals("white")){
            who[5]= 1;
            counter--;
            }
        }while (counter > 1);


    if (counter == 1 ){
        System.out.println("It was: ");
        for(int i = 0;i<6;i++){
            if (who[i] == 0){
                System.out.println(whoRemains[i]);

            }
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: "More efficient way to write this code" - might be better to change this to a more descriptive title so reviewers will  immediately know what the code is doing.

Answer (score 5):

There are several problems with this program, as you are aware.

- The name of a class should *always* start with a capital letter.  This is so that you don't get confused with instances which should always start with a lowercase letter.
- You're using magic numbers or what is intended to be constants used in your program.  While it's true you're not likely to have more than 6 names, it is true that you may have less in a future version.  Best practice dictates that you should see the constant 6 at *most* once, better still if you can remove it entirely (if you think about it, what is 6 except the length of your array?  You need not declare it if it is already available).
- You're using an int array to keep track of which names haven't been eliminated, and while effective, there is a far simpler way to manage this.  Use a HashSet.  If the name is contained in the hashset, you remove it.  At each iteration, simply show contents of your hashset.  HashSet has a `size()` method so you don't even need to use counter.
- Best practice dictates that you should expect erroneous input from the user.  While it's true that you may be the only one using it, better that it works also when your girlfriend tries it out.  A couple things that come to mind include trimming input and transforming into lowercase to compare, so " White" would work just as well as "white".
- The names have been extracted as a constant.  The whole program is using static methods, though even if it weren't, the names remain the same with any instance, so I would make it a static constant in the containing class.
- Don't be afraid to break up your program into bite-sized pieces.  It may seem trivial to create a method for one line, but if you could assign a name to that task, it is likely something you could modularize and it will serve you well in future maintenance of the program.  Try to make each line in your main as easy to read as you would explain each step to your friend (i.e. loadNamesSet, printNames, updateNames, etc.)
- If you find yourself with many if clauses, especially one for each array index, you're probably doing something wrong.  You should try to generalize when you use arrays, and if you can't, you shouldn't be using arrays.  In this case, you could create a method which given a string, will loop all elements in your array, and if it matches, will set the value of who at the position where it matched (see below).  Note that HashSet also means we won't have to do it this way, though I thought you might like to see what it would look like:

  > ```
  > private void updateWho(String name) {
  >   for(int i=0; i<whoRemains.length; i++) {
  >     if(whoRemains[i].equals(name)) {
  >       who[i]=1;
  >       break;
  >     }
  >   }
  > }
  > ```

With all these things in mind, this is how I would write the same program:

```
package clue;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    private final static String[] NAMES_LIST = new String[] { "green", "mustard", "peacock",
            "plum", "scarlet", "white" };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Load hash set
        HashSet<String> names = loadNamesSet();

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {
            // Show current names list
            printNames(names);

            // Remove name if it exists
            String guess = sc.next();
            updateNames(names, guess);
        } while (names.size() > 1);

        // Show remaining
        System.out.println("It was: " + names.iterator().next());
    }

    private static boolean updateNames(Collection<String> names, String guess) {
        String betterGuess = guess.trim().toLowerCase();
        return names.remove(betterGuess);
    }

    private static void printNames(HashSet<String> names) {
        System.out.println("Remaing People: ");
        for(String name : names) {
            System.out.println(name);
        }
    }

    private static HashSet<String> loadNamesSet() {
        HashSet<String> names = new HashSet<String>();
        for(String name : NAMES_LIST) {
            names.add(name);
        }
        return names;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that the order of a `HashSet` is not maintained.  If this were important, than replace `HashSet` with `LinkedHashSet`.